# URL Encode and Decode Special character in Java

Tags: java, urlencode

In Java, I need to use HTTP Post to send request to server, but if in the parameter of the URL contains some special character it throws below Exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in
>   escape (%) pattern - For input string:
>   "&'"

The code to send data

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL); 

   String sessionId = RequestUtil.getRequest().getSession().getId();
   String data = arg.getData().toString();

   List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();   
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(param1, data));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(param2, sessionId));
         httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));           

   HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

And at the server side, i use the below code to read information

```
 String data = request.getParameter(param1);
   if (data != null) {
    actionArg = new ChannelArg(URLDecoder.decode(data, "UTF-8"));
   }
```

The code works correctly but if i input some special character like [aああ#$%&'(<>?/.,あああああ], it will throw exception. I wonder if someone could help me some hint to be able to encode and decode special characters?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly url encoder will not solve your problem. I had this problem and used a custom utility. I remember this I got from googling ;).

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=96

Comment: I oversaw a better solutions. Our friends from apache have StringEscapeUtils (org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils). Please check it if it works.

Answer (score 9):

To encode text for safe passage through the internets:

```
import java.net.*;
...
try {
    encodedValue= URLEncoder.encode(rawValue, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) { }
```

And to decode:

```
try {
    decodedValue = URLDecoder.decode(rawValue, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) { }
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, but as you can see in my code, i use UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8") at client site to encode my object data and at server side, i used URLDecoder.decode(data, "UTF-8") to decode. It worked correctly with Japanese characters but the problem only came up when i input some character like [#$%&'(<>?/.,]

Answer (score 3):

```
String data = request.getParameter(param1);
```

If this is the [servlet API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29), the parameters have already been decoded. No further handling of percent-encoding is necessary.

---

*I haven't used HttpClient, but ensure it is sending the encoding in the header:*

```
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

*Or, if you must, set the known encoding before any `getParameter` calls:*

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

try guava

use com.google.common.net.UrlEscapers

it works fine with chinese

like this:

```
Escaper escaper = UrlEscapers.urlFragmentEscaper();
String result = escaper.escape(yoururl);
```