# Revert escaping special characters

Tags: java, javascript

I have a string in java that looks like this `"&#039;&#039;&#039;&#039;&lt;&gt;!@#$%^&amp"`, this was escaped in javascript. I need to obtain the original string before escaping the special characters, which is `"''''<>!@#$%^&*()"`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841331/url-encode-and-decode-special-character-in-java

Comment: Your question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) for this.

> For example, the string "&lt;Fran&ccedil;ais&gt;" will become "<Français>"

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how it was encoded to reverse it.

If it was URL encoded (which looks likely) then Java has a built in `URLDecoder` class.

```
URLDecoder.decode(message, encoding);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons provides utilities for this.

`org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(String string)` should be what you want.

Check out the API [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)